# Install latest Mondrian on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, mondrian

I am a little lost. I want to install Mondrian on a tomcat server. However the documentation is heavily outdated. It still refers to the .war file which is discontinued for a long time. 
I do not want to install an old version but I cannot find anything on how to install Mondrian in its latest version.

I am aware of xMondrian but there has to be a way to install the original Mondrian! Or am I missing something?

Can anybody help me?

("War never changes." doesnt seem to aply here :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xMondrian.war to run latest mondrian. Follow these steps

1) Download xMondrian.war, put it in your tomcat webapps directory.
2) remove mondrian-.jar from xmondrian libs folder.
3) download latest mondrian jar (say mondrian 4.4) and put it in libs.
4) clone https://github.com/olap4j/olap4j-xmlaserver in separate location and build jar with master branch.
5) copy generated olap4j-xmlaserver jar to xmondrian libs folder.
6) configure your datasource.xml
7) restart tomcat.

Done

You can now use xmla interface or whatever client available in xmondrian war to connect cubes

Comment: Yes, this is the xMondrian approach, which I used now too because of the lack of another solution. 
But that was NOT the question. How do I use Mondrian (not xMondrian) in its latest version.

Comment: I think your question was to deploy latest Mondrian on tomcat server rt? xMondrian is just a web application that you can use to run any version of Mondrian. You just need to replace old jars with latest Mondrian jars in WEB-INF/libs.

Comment: Ahhhh! Ok! See, that was the missing link! I overlooked your point three, sorry.
Thank you!

Comment: @shaipraj I need to implement Mondrian XMLA interface, one option is to use XMondrian, the other option [olap4j-xmlaserver](https://github.com/olap4j/olap4j-xmlaserver) what's the difference between the two? Since `olap4j-xmlaserver`  is `olap4j` sister project it seems to be the way to go.